# How do I pass a url parameter to AJAX jquery when the datatype is XML?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So basically I'd like to pass an id parameter to the url `www.example.php` used an example here , but the datatype is xml .. I know how to do this when it is GET or POST .. How do I do this ?  I tried to look it up on google but I can't find this . `example.php` is supposed to dynamically generate xml and store echo it in a variable .. I'd just like to pass it a parameter so I can get the id on example.php as  `$_GET['id']`, treating it as `example.php?id=1` for example .. how do I do this when the datatype is XML ?

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.example.php',
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function(doc) {
        $(doc).find('event').each(function() {
            if($(this).find("date").text() !="") {
                event_data.push($(this).find("date").text());
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: GET and POST aren't datatypes. What you are doing here is a GET or POST request, so do it the same way you would with any other GET or POST request.

Comment: try looking at the docs!  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: why not just add `?=id` to the url of the ajax call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dataType` is telling what you are expecting from the server response, not what you are sending. If server expects some id parameter from you, then you just send it as usual.